# What is the meaning of field keyword in LLVM tablegen?

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to learn LLVM tablegen. http://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/LangRef.html shows that `field` keyword exists but doesn't explain its meaning. Does anybody know what it means?

I found the following code in a [tutorial](http://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/llvmstructure.html)

```
class Cpu0Reg<string n> : Register<n> {
  field bits<4> Num;
  let Namespace = "Cpu0";
}
```

Can I do the following instead (notice the `field` keyword is missing)

```
class Cpu0Reg<string n> : Register<n> {
  bits<4> Num;
  let Namespace = "Cpu0";
}
```

Later in the tutorial I found this code (notice the `bits<20> addr`, it doesn't have `field` keyword in front of it):

```
class FMem<bits<8> op, dag outs, dag ins, string asmstr, list<dag> pattern,
          InstrItinClass itin>: FL<op, outs, ins, asmstr, pattern, itin> {
  bits<20> addr;
  let Inst{19-16} = addr{19-16};
  let Inst{15-0}  = addr{15-0};
  let DecoderMethod = "DecodeMem";
}
```

So what is the difference between `field bits<n>` and `bits<n>` and what does `field` keyword do?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As far as I can tell, it does nothing**, unless you use positionally-encoded operands (which you should not be using).

---

Follow me as I go code diving:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/8ff4fe417f7993462cf4e16a0eb43b09bc26ad36/lib/TableGen/TGParser.cpp#L1707

This comment on line 1691 suggests that the `field` is optional.

```
///  Declaration ::= FIELD? Type ID ('=' Value)?
```

Note that the purpose of these lines is to simply remove the `field` token if it exists.

```
// Read the field prefix if present.
bool HasField = Lex.getCode() == tgtok::Field;
if (HasField) Lex.Lex();
```

The presence of `field` is also noted in the variable `HasField`, which is passed into the constructor of `RecordVal` on line 1722.

```
RecordVal::RecordVal(StringRef N, RecTy *T, bool P)
  : Name(StringInit::get(N)), TyAndPrefix(T, P) {
  Value = UnsetInit::get()->convertInitializerTo(T);
  assert(Value && "Cannot create unset value for current type!");
}
```

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/8ff4fe417f7993462cf4e16a0eb43b09bc26ad36/lib/TableGen/Record.cpp#L1583

RecordVal initializes `TyAndPrefix`, a pair of (type, bool). The bool stores whether the `field` prefix was used in the declaration. The presence of `field` is queried using `RecordVal::getPrefix`.

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getPrefix+path%3Autils%2FTableGen+path%3Alib%2FTableGen&type=Code

This search turns up no uses, apart from the presence of `field` inhibiting processing of positionally-encoded operands.

Comment: For example, _Mips/MicroMips32r6InstrFormats.td_ doesn't use _field_. It just uses: _bits<16> Inst;_